# Android Manifest File: App Supports Tablets, but is marked "not compatible" in market?

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, android-permissions, tablet

I've been reading several other things on the forum for handling the Manifest File. Though I've found answers; it still doesn't address my particular issue.  My application is designed for any phone or tablet, but Google's Play Store says "Not Compatible."  I'm attempting to make the application available to phones and tablets (cellular or just wifi).
Any assistance would be terrific, thank you in advance.  I'm clearly missing something in this manifest file.

These are the permissions requesting:

```
android.permission.INTERNET, 
android.permission.CALL_PHONE, 
android.permission.SEND_SMS, 
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, 
android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE, 
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, 
android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE, 
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, 
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
```

Features:

```
android.hardware.location, 
android.hardware.location, 
android.hardware.location.network, 
android.hardware.touchscreen, 
android.hardware.wifi
```

It is quite an odd error; plus the methodology in which it appears to request is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could think that some tablets don't have `call_phone` permission, since they only have wifi?
Are you sure the tablet has 3g functionality? (Also for the `sms`)

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply; so I looked into the permission a little further.  So I changed my permission request to this: `<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.telephony android:required="false" />` instead of leaving it completely out. That appears to of fixed it.  Thanks for the assistance Peter.

Comment: @Greg, it looks like this answer solved your issue, so please click the check mark to accept it.

Answer (score 6):

For simplicity in case someone looks for my exact resolution; it is as follows:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.telephony android:required="false" />`

Once that was added instead of leaving it out, it appears to of triggered correctly.