# Android : WIFI Only Tablets Marked Incompatible on PlayStore

Tags: android, google-play, native, android-permissions, android-wifi

I have an App on Play Store which can be installed by all Devices Except the Wifi only devices (who do not have SIM) , How to make the Application Compatible with those devices too ?
Below is My Manifest file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.mypackage"
    android:exported="false"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal">
    <!-- 11 -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.pixako.trackn.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.pixako.trackn.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <protected-broadcast android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" /> <!-- Smart watch permission -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.wmanager.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" /> <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name="com.pixako.application.AppDelegate"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemes"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup"> MyClasses </application> </manifest>

asking run time permissions too

    int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 20;
        String[] permissions = new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
                Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY,
                Manifest.permission.SET_ALARM,
                "",
                ""
        };
    
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            permissions[9] = Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE;
            permissions[10] = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION;
        }
    
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            permissions[9] = Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE;
        }
    
        LoginProcessActivity.super.requestAppPermissions(permissions, R.string.runtime_permissions_txt
                    , REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
```

have already implemented the changes described in this issue
[Android Manifest File: App Supports Tablets, but is marked "not compatible" in market?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842704/android-manifest-file-app-supports-tablets-but-is-marked-not-compatible-in-m)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27956903/my-app-is-not-compatible-on-wifi-only-devices